# Terraform Variable looping to generate properties

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have to admit, this is the first time I have to ask something that I dont even myself know how to ask for it or explain, so here is my code.
It worth explains that, for specific reasons I CANNOT change the output resource, this, the metadata sent to the resource has to stay as is, otherwise it will cause a recreate and I dont want that.

currently I have a terraform code that uses static/fixed variables like this

```
user1_name="Ed"
user1_Age ="10"
user2_name="Mat"
user2_Age ="20"
```

and then those hard typed variables get used in several places, but most importanly they are passed as metadata to instances, like so

```
resource "google_compute_instance_template" "mytemplate" {
  ...
  metadata = {
    othervalues     = var.other     
    user1_name      = var.user1_name
    user1_Age       = var.user1_Age
    user2_name      = var.user2_name
    user2_Age       = var.user2_Age
  }
  ...
}
```

I am not an expert on terraform, thus asking, but I know for fact this is 100% ugly and wrong, and I need to use lists or array or whatever, so I am changing my declarations to this:

```
users = [
  { "name" : "yo", "age" : "10",  "last" : "other" },
  { "name" : "El", "age" : "20",  "last" : "other" }
]
```

but then, how do i get around to generate the same result for that resource? The resulting resource has to still have the same metadata as shown.
Assuming of course that the order of the users will be used as the "index" of the value, first one gets user1_name and so on...

I assume I need to use a for_each loop in there but cant figure out how to get around a loop inside properties of a resource

Not sure if I make myself clear on this, probably not, but didn't found a better way to explain.

Comment: Please replace the first block of code with your proposed variable declaration that includes the theoretical `default` from your third code block, and also update with your desired `output` value structure. Otherwise, we do not know the "same values for the output".

Comment: If you are talking about output in terms of how to output the variable value to use in the resource block, then yes, I would suggest using `for_each` and `dynamic` block for metadata if applicable.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I'm not sure I understand your request, but maybe I made a mistake in my redaction, I don't use or need any output, all I want is use the 3rd block of variables in the resource, I'll fix the redaction

Comment: @MarkoE thats exactly what I want, but how do you go around using for_each on that specific part of the resource? I couldnt figure it out

Comment: @MarkoE dig further and found the dynamic "setting" documentation, I was able to make it work for other block types, ie, disks, network_interfaces but not for metadata, because aparently metadate needs a = sign, metadata = {}  and others dont...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your example it seems like your intent is for these to all ultimately appear as a single map with keys built from two parts.

Your example doesn't make clear what the relationship is between `user1` and `Ed`, though: your first example shows that "user1's" name is Ed, but in your example of the data structure you want to create there is only one "name" and it isn't clear to me whether that name would replace "user1" or "Ed" from your first example.

Instead, I'm going to take a slightly different variable structure which still maintains both the key like "user1" *and* the name attribute, like this:

```
variable "users" {
  type = map(object({
    name = string
    age  = number
  })
}

locals {
  # First we'll transform the map of objects into a
  # flat set of key/attribute/value objects, because
  # that's easier to work with when we generate the
  # flattened map below.
  users_flat = flatten([
    for key, user in var.users : [
      for attr, value in user : {
        key   = key
        attr  = attr
        value = value
      }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "google_compute_instance_template" "mytemplate" {
  metadata = merge(
    {
      othervalues = var.other
    },
    {
      for vo in local.users_flat : "${vo.key}_${vo.attr}" => vo.value
    }
  )
}
```

`local.users_flat` here is an intermediate data structure that flattens the two-level heirarchy of keys and object attributes from the input. It would be shaped something like this:

```
[
  { key = "user1", attr = "name", value = "Ed" },
  { key = "user1", attr = "age", value = 10 },
  { key = "user2", attr = "name", value = "Mat" },
  { key = "user2", attr = "age", value = 20 },
]
```

The `merge` call in the `metadata` argument then merges a directly-configured mapping of "other values" with a generated mapping derived from `local.users_flat`, shaped like this:

```
{
  "user1_name" = "Ed"
  "user1_age"  = 10
  "user2_name" = "Mat"
  "user2_age"  = 20
}
```

From the perspective of the caller of the module, the `users` variable should be defined with the following value in order to get the above results:

```
  users = {
    user1 = {
      name = "Ed"
      age  = 10
    }
    user2 = {
      name = "Mat"
      age  = 20
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, I didn't fully test it, but clearly this is the approach I need, Thank you very much for taking the time to explain and write examples.

The only thing I would like to mod is the values from the caller perspective
With your example, for each new  user added I need to increment the number and keep  track of it, Ideally it shouldn't be, as I don't need it for anything, user1 is not required, All I need is each user name and age only.

I.e: users = [{ name="Ed", age=10 },  { name="Mat", age=20 }]

But I will see if i can figure that one by myself !! :)

Comment: Commenting myself, I totally made it work, I was able to either change the type of the users from map to a set so they dont require a key, but I ofcourse cannot have duplicates so i can use an index, or leave it as map and use use a integer as key.
Either way I made it work the way I need and I can move forward.

THANKS A LOT, really appreciated, took you a lot of time to explain but you did it anyways...

Answer (score 0):

`metadata` is **not a block**, but a regular attribute of type `map`. So you can do:

```
# it would be better to use map, not list for users:
variable "users"
  default {
   user1 =  { "name" : "yo", "age" : "10",  "last" : "other" },
   user2 =  { "name" : "El", "age" : "20",  "last" : "other" }
   }
}

resource "google_compute_instance_template" "mytemplate" {
  
  for_each = var.users

  metadata = each.value
  #...
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but that will generate one mytemplate for each users, which is not the outcome I need.
It needs to be a SINGLE resource, with N metadata values as per users.... 
But we are getting closer :

Comment: @Smoke I don't think you can't do this. In my view there can be only one `metadata` in `google_compute_instance_template`. Where did you find that you can have multiple `metadata`?

Comment: not multiple metadatas, only one metadata with all the values values in it
for this example metadata = { name1=yo, name2=El } and so on